# Is it possible to stick a image onto one face of 3d object in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I am currently working on a project with OpenGL. I wanted to stick an image onto the sign below to make it more realistic. Is there a way to do this with OpenGL? Maybe loading the image in and paint it onto the shape?

[image: The sign]

Here is the code to create the block of sign:

```
//Set the size and position
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-550.0, 500.0, fltSignOffset);
glScalef(700.0, 150.0, 20.0);

//Create the shape
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0.0, 0.55, 0.27); //Use SpringGreen4 for sign
glutSolidCube(1);

//Create the wireframe of the shape
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glutWireCube(1);

glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Yes, you need to research *textures*.

Comment: Yes there is a way. It's called texture mapping and explaining it all probably doesn't fit into the SO format. You'll find thousands of tutorials on the internet, e.g., https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures and https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/…

Comment: If you are still at the learning stage, I suggest you stop using the legacy OpenGL fixed pipline (removed 2008)  https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline and move to OpenGL 3.1+  This should future proof your efforts to lean OpenGL.

Comment: @RichardCritten idk - the fixed pipeline *works just fine*, is not terrible for low quality graphics, and is much much easier to get started with. Do remember to learn shaders eventually though.

Comment: @user253751 I made no comment on the functionality of OpenGL at all. I was just trying to inform the OP of the status of the OpenGL API so they could make an informed decision and make the best use of their valuable time.  If they have to work on a legacy project that decision is out of their hands anyway.

Comment: @RichardCritten I say it because I learned the fixed function pipeline first, and I got plenty of these comments, and I found them annoying and not helpful. Eventually I decided to learn the shader pipeline because I wanted to.